# White Holes Evidences

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, experimental-physics, quantum-gravity, white-holes

It is well known that in the canonical quantization program for quantum gravity, like LQG/Wheeler-De Witt/Polymer QM,
almost every prescription when applied to cosmology/gravitational collapse leads to the avoidance of the singularity via a bounce. In the context of gravitational collapse, this give rise to white holes formation: after falling inside the black hole the star bounces producing a white hole.

Since for external stationary observers, like us, the star never even fall inside the horizon due to time dilation, how could evidence of such phenomena be obtained?
Are there ways to see, for a stationary observer, if the star bounce off to form a white hole for stationary observers? What evidence should we find to state that an astronomical object is a white hole?

A sample reference about the topic: https://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1361-6382/aae550 https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.04264

Comment: I think people there seem to use some newer meaning of a white hole. Originally it was the opposite end of a BH-WH pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matter is quite complicated. By taking various symmetry-reduced canonical quantization models, one does indeed generically get "bounces" and various white hole/black hole states. However, this comes about by restricting only to monopole/spherically symmetric modes. When one considers the other modes, non-spherical modes of all the relevant physical fields at least to linear order, one gets Hawking radiation and thus evaporation of black holes. This is recognized even by people such as Ashtekar (see e.g. the recent preprint on regular black holes, [Ashtekar et al. (2023)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.01309.pdf)).

The other issue with the bounce is that at face value the bounces produced by these symmetry-reduced models typically spit the matter into other universes, not ours. From that you would get no observational signatures, of course. You would have to argue that matter is spitting *from other universes* into ours, which is a complete black box for predictions.

The time-scale of the occurence of the bounce (in some global foliation of the space-time) is typically similar to the [Page time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation#Black_hole_evaporation), the time by which the black hole evaporates. This means that the matter may evaporate before it reaches the bounce (again, in the global foliation picture). In other scenarios, the horizon disappears due to evaporatio and some residue, partially evaporated matter is spat out after some kind of bounce. These are all "scenarios" however, there is no serious computation showing this explicitly.

If you were looking for an observational signature, it is really unclear what that should be, since the result should be heavily evaporated by quantum effects and we do not know what that should be. However, the basic assumption would be that the matter perhaps looks a bit like matter upon collapse, i.e., signatures similar to supernovae. Since the matter in collapse likely reaches higher temperatures/densities, one should see signatures of nuclear processes only possible at higher energies and the corresponding heavy elements. Other possibilities include high-energy cosmic rays and beyond-standard model particles etc. due to very high energy processes. However, nobody really knows.

Comment: Thank you, a very detailed answer. That is what i was looking for